# Font-face with text shadow giving poor result

Tags: font-face, css

I've used font-face with text shadow which looks good both in FF 3.6 and IE 8 in windows7. In windows XP, however, it looks ok in IE but the text is not clear in Firefox 3.6. It loads and its clear for a moment but it feels that when shadow is applied it makes the font result poor. Any ideas?

Comment: i wonder how ot could look ok in IE. text-shadow is not supported by IE..

Comment: Issue likely with the font files used in the font-face. CSS code and links to the font files would help.

Comment: Windows sucks at font rendering. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @meo: It looks OK on IE precisely because IE can't apply any text shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Try these lines of code

```
html
{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

READ >> [CSS Text-Rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-rendering)